# Beamer: Mixing absolute overlays with relative overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have the following code snippet that creates the overlays in the desired order. However, setting the `beamerpauses`-counter myself is quite ugly. How can I avoid setting the counter myself and get the same output? The problem seems to come from mixing `\only` with relative overlay numbers, but I'm not sure how to avoid this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide}
\begin{itemize}
\item Blabla
\item Blabla
\item<3-> Blabla
\end{itemize}
\only<1-2>{
    A\only<2>{B}
}
\only<3->{ \setcounter{beamerpauses}{3}
    \only<+>{First:}
    \only<.>{$1+1=$}
    \only<+>{$2$}
    \only<+>{Second:}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tricky one, but doable if you work systematically. You might want to look at my [guide to `beamer` overlays](http://www.texdev.net/2014/01/17/the-beamer-slide-overlay-concept/) (also available as a [*TUGboat* article](https://www.tug.org/members/TUGboat/tb35-1/tb109wright.pdf), currently only to TUG members).

What you need to do is use the idea of relative slide positions, indicated by `+`, `.` and numbers in parenthesis. I'll explain the detail in comments in the code (trying to gie this up-front is tricky):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide}
\begin{itemize}
  % First item on slide 1 onwards. The `+` will be replaced here by a `1` here:
  % of course if you add material before hand absolute value will change!
  \item<+-> Blabla
  % Second item on same slide as first: `.` repeats the previous number
  \item<.-> Blabla
  % Third item appears on third slide: `+` is slide 2 here, so `+(1)` is slide 3.
  \item<+(1)-> Blabla
\end{itemize}
% Repeat the preceding `+` (`2`) but back-up one to `1`, with the second `.`
% replaced simply by `2`.
\only<.(-1)-.>{A}%
% Again, repeat `2` (the last value `+` stood for)
\only<.>{B}%
% Auto-increment `+` to `3` and insert
\only<+>{First:}%
% Repeat `3` again
\only<.>{$1+1=$}%
% Two simple auto-increments
\only<+>{$2$}%
\only<+>{Second:}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Done this way, nothing is hard-coded so it should be possible to use the code flexibly.

(To do this sort of thing, I'd start with the hard-coded numbers then replace one at a time by the relative specs.)

Comment: It seems the main task is to unroll the nested `\only` usages, thanks! The link does not seem to work.

Comment: @HeinrichOdy Yes, nested conditionals are risky (the `+` gets incremented _each time you use it_, so `\only<+>{\only<+> ...` turns into something like `\only<3>{\only<4> ...`.